# -bash : rvictl: command not found, Mac book pro OS X 10.7.5 & Xcode 4.6

Tags: macos, networking

I want to debug some network bug with my application ,I found a way to create rvi to trace, But I even can't finish step 1 :

rvictl -s 
-bash : rvictl: command not found

what should I do ?
I follow the site: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1176/_index.html

help! thanks

Comment: Did I need to install any tools like get rivctl?

Answer (score 17):

**Mavericks and beyond:** You need to install XCode from the App Store, and **then** you need to launch XCode once, and accept installation of additional tools. Restart your terminal. Good to go.

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73123).
In summary, the link above explains that the issue may stem from installing Xcode without installing the additional components.
Check rvictl is installed by looking for the `/usr/bin/rvictl` folder. If it does not exist, then rvictl is not installed. To install the packages, open your application folder through finder, right click on the Xcode app, and follow the path below to find the items which need to be installed manually:

- Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDevice.pkg
- Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg

Restart your terminal and.... Voila !! it should work now.

**CATALINA UPDATE**.

Based @KarthicRaghupathi's comments. the rvictl location was changed in Catalina. The rvictl file is now located at `/Library/Apple/usr/bin`.
The rest of the process stays the same as above.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. `rvictl` was still not being found even after installing `MobileDevice.pkg` and `MobileDeviceDevelopment.pkg`. In macOS 10.15.1 (19B88) and Xcode 11.2 (11B52), the location where this executable can be found is `/Library/Apple/usr/bin`.

Comment: @KarthicRaghupathi you should post this as a full answer to spare all Catalina (and later) users some headaches

Comment: @ErnestoElsäßer Thanks! The answer here has been updated to include this information. I think that is good enough for users to find.

Comment: **Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/MobileDevice.pkg** does not exist

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky did you install xcode additional components?

Comment: @E.N.D All other components were installed.  I am running MacOS Catalina.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky what part of the path exists on your system? can you see the "Resources" folder?

Comment: Had to install 12GB Xcode for this small tool

Comment: For M1 mac users had to do few more steps finally to make it work. Starting device fails. You should enable system extension following this link, after that when u try rvictl command again should allow update and another restart, https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-security-settings-startup-disk-a-mac-mchl768f7291/mac

Answer (score 1):

I'm using macOS Catalina and Xcode 11, Could able to find rvictl file in `/Library/Apple/usr/bin.` but still got the same error

> -bash : rvictl: command not found

Tried all provided solution nothing worked for me. Adding sudo saved me,

```
sudo rvictl -s [DEVICE UDID]
```

[or]

```
sudo /Library/Apple/usr/bin/rvictl -s [DEVICE UDID]
```

This may help some one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Command Line Tools for Xcode, available here:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#
That includes the rvictl program.

Comment: the command line tools for 10.10 apparently do not include the `rvictl`
 program - I get the error message: `command not found`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like default location and installed location of `rvictl` on Catalina are different.
`rvictl` should be installed by Xcode. Look for it at path: `/Library/Apple/usr/bin/rvictl`.  The default shell has `/Library/Apple/usr/bin/` in its path, either customise it or provide full qualified path i.e

```
/Library/Apple/usr/bin/rvictl -s 00008020-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/392193#392193

Answer (score -1):

When you say:  the command line tools for 10.10 apparently do not include the rvictl program - I get the error message: command not found

You need to see the comment above:  Mavericks and beyond: You need to install XCode from the App Store, and then you need to launch XCode once, and accept installation of additional tools. Restart your terminal.

It will then appear.